# Mutable reference in object returned from Iterator

Tags: rust

I want to create an `Iterator` capable of exposing neighbouring items as well. As long as I don't want to also change these items, it is fine and easy. But how to make a mutable variant of the same structure?

Immutable:

```
struct NearestNeighbours2D<'a, T> {
    mid: &'a T,
    left: &'a T,
    right: &'a T,
    top: &'a T,
    bot: &'a T,
}

struct EnumerateNearestNeighbours2D<'a, I>
where I: std::ops::Index<usize> {
    x: usize,
    y: usize,
    width: usize,
    height: usize,
    inner: &'a I
}

impl<'a, I: std::ops::Index<usize>> Iterator for EnumerateNearestNeighbours2D<'a, I>
where <I as std::ops::Index<usize>>::Output: std::marker::Sized {
    
    type Item = NearestNeighbours2D<'a, I::Output>;
    fn next(&mut self) -> std::option::Option<<Self as std::iter::Iterator>::Item> {

        let (top, left, mid, right, bot) = (
            (self.y - 1) * self.width + self.x,
            self.y * self.width + self.x - 1,
            self.y * self.width + self.x,
            self.y * self.width + self.x + 1,
            (self.y + 1) * self.width + self.x,
        );

        Some(
            NearestNeighbours2D {
                mid: &self.inner[mid],
                left: &self.inner[left],
                right: &self.inner[right],
                top: &self.inner[top],
                bot: &self.inner[bot],
            }
        )
    }
}
```

Mutable variant that doesn't work due to lifetimes:

```
struct NearestNeighbours2DMut<'a, T> {
    mid: &'a mut T,
    left: &'a mut T,
    right: &'a mut T,
    top: &'a mut T,
    bot: &'a mut T,
}

struct EnumerateNearestNeighbours2DMut<'a, I>
where I: std::ops::IndexMut<usize> {
    x: usize,
    y: usize,
    width: usize,
    height: usize,
    inner: &'a mut I
}

impl<'a, I: std::ops::IndexMut<usize>> Iterator for EnumerateNearestNeighbours2DMut<'a, I>
where <I as std::ops::Index<usize>>::Output: std::marker::Sized {
    
    type Item = NearestNeighbours2DMut<'a, I::Output>;
    fn next(&mut self) -> std::option::Option<<Self as std::iter::Iterator>::Item> {

        let (top, left, mid, right, bot) = (
            (self.y - 1) * self.width + self.x,
            self.y * self.width + self.x - 1,
            self.y * self.width + self.x,
            self.y * self.width + self.x + 1,
            (self.y + 1) * self.width + self.x,
        );

        Some(
            NearestNeighbours2DMut {
                mid: &mut self.inner[mid],
                left: &mut self.inner[left],
                right: &mut self.inner[right],
                top: &mut self.inner[top],
                bot: &mut self.inner[bot],
            }
        )
    }
}
```

Compiler points that:

```
error[E0495]: cannot infer an appropriate lifetime for lifetime parameter in function call due to conflicting requirements
   --> src\lib.rs:99:27
    |
99  |                 mid: &mut self.inner[mid],
    |                           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    |
```

Comment: @trentcl could you please take a look at that one as well?

Comment: FYI, people don't get notifications for being @ed in comments unless they are the author of the post being commented on or have commented previously on the same post. But I happen to be here anyway so I will take a look :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no way `EnumerateNearestNeighbors2DMut` can be made correctly -- it is unsound. Each time you call `next` you get `&mut` references that potentially overlap with `&mut` references that were returned from the previous call to `next`. This means, if it worked, it would be violating the rules of references by creating aliased `&mut`s.

This is the same reason that there is a [`std::slice::Windows`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/slice/struct.Windows.html), but no `WindowsMut` (although `ChunksMut` is fine because the chunks are non-overlapping).

Some problems ([here's one example](/q/60072498/3650362)) give similar-looking error messages, but are actually solvable (in some cases with `unsafe`) because the items being referenced are in fact non-overlapping. Those solutions don't work here. If you could [write an iterator that returns references to itself](/q/30422177/3650362) (a "streaming iterator"), the API could be made sound. However, `Iterator` doesn't allow this.

Here are three possible options for you. There are certainly others.

- Don't allow mutable iteration (with neighbors) at all. Just expose iteration via shared (`&`) reference, and if you need to mutate the original grid, instead create a modified copy and swap it with the original after you're done iterating. This is frequently what you want anyway, if you're writing something like an image filter or a cellular automaton where each output depends on multiple inputs.
- Accept a closure and use internal iteration in your API instead of external iteration. So instead of something like this:

  ```
  for neighbors in array.enumerate_2d_neighbors_mut() {
      println!("{}", neighbors.top);
  }
  ```

  you would write something like this:

  ```
  array.foreach_2d_neighbors_mut(|neighbors| {
      println!("{}", neighbors.top);
  });
  ```

  In this case the references to `array`'s items are taken in a `for` loop inside the `foreach_2d_neighbors_mut` method and do not escape it. This API can be written pretty easily, even without `unsafe` code.
- Use interior mutability (`Cell`, `RefCell`, `Atomic???`, etc.) to mutate through a `&` reference instead of needing `&mut`. Depending on what you're doing this might be the right way to go. Be aware that you can [sneakily use `Cell` for interior mutability without having to change the type `I`, when `I` is a slice or vector](https://ryhl.io/blog/temporary-shared-mutation/). However this would not be my first choice most of the time.

Comment: I googled `Cell` and first thing it points is exactly the mistake I made:
"[...] it is only possible to have one of the following: Having several immutable references (&T) to the object (also known as aliasing). Having one mutable reference (&mut T) to the object (also known as mutability).". I only need it for reading to "blend" neighbouring elements and save in different buffer, but I was wondering "what if" in case I needed it in the future :D